# Spreading resistance of a microelectrode in a bath

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, maxwell-equations

I have a question regarding the spreading resistance, or series resistance, around a glass microelectrode in a bath (a conducting fluid with uniform resistivity $\rho$). The bath is grounded at a far distance from the electrode, and a current $I$ is applied through the electrode.  The electrode can be approximated with a cone that is broken off to create a tip orifice (see figure below). A perhaps acceptable solution I came up with would be something along these lines:

Assume a spherical shell centered around the electrode tip (or more precisely at the vertex of the angle $\alpha$) with resistivity $\rho$. The spherical surface $A$ would be the whole sphere minus the spherical cap that is "cut out" by the electrode,

$$A=4\pi r^2-2\pi r^2(1-\cos{(\alpha/2)})=4\pi r^2 \cos^2{(\alpha/4)}.$$

The resistance of the spherical shell is then

$$dR=\frac{\rho}{A} dr=\frac{\rho}{4\pi r^2 \cos^2{(\alpha/4)}} dr.$$

We then integrate from the microelectrode tip radius $a$ to infinity,

$$R=\int_{a}^{\infty}  \frac{\rho}{4\pi r^2 \cos^2{(\alpha/4)}} dr=\frac{\rho}{4\pi a \cos^2{(\alpha/4)}}.$$

However, I believe this deviates from a more correct depiction obtained by solving the Laplace equation for this geometry. In electrophysiology it is customary to describe the spreading resistance of a Maxwell contact (e.g., an ion chanel through a membrane) by $\frac{\rho}{\pi a} $ (by approximating with half-space hemispheres) whereas the true solution (used in electronics textbooks) is $\frac{\rho}{2a} $ (see e.g., [Maxwell contact](http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/sem/maxwell/maxwell.php)).

I can see that at least three problems arise with my solution:

1. My solution ignores the resistance close to the tip (especially along the longitudinal axis) since I integrate from $a$.
2. The geometry for the electrical field around the tip is not solved for. At a large distance I guess it would be near perpendicular to a spherical shell but not in the vicinity of the tip.
3. The spherical shells are integrated from the vertex and not from the tip.

Note that I am not interested in the resistance of the microelectrode itself, but rather the series resistance in the bath.

I know my Maxwell not good enough to solve this problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: "I have been dealing with an issue regarding the spreading restistance around a glass microelectrode in a bath." - I think that your question gets off to a bad start because even this first sentence is unclear. What do you mean by "the spreading resistance"? What is this "bath"? Is it a bath of electrically conducting fluid which has uniform electrical conductivity throughout it? You need to use at least a couple of sentences to fully and clearly describe the setup.